# Google Script Editor - Cannot find method formatDate(object,string,string)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Scripts, and I'm trying to create a macro that will automatically filter a spreadsheet based on a given date. However, I keep getting an error when I try to reformat the dates. The second line results in the error, "Cannot find method formatDate(object,string,string)"

This is working elsewhere in my script on a single cell value, but not for this array. How can I reformat all the dates to my desired format?

```
var filterMonthRange = sh.getRange('B2:B'+sh.getLastRow()).getValues();
var filterMonthRange = Utilities.formatDate(filterMonthRange, "GMT", "MMMMM YYYY");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You want to convert the date object to the format of `MMMMM YYYY`.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

`date` of `Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)` is required to be the date object. The reason of the error is that an array is used instead of the date object.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the values retrieved from cells "B2:B" are converted with `Utilities.formatDate()`.

#### Modified script:

Please modify your script as follows.

From:

```
var filterMonthRange = Utilities.formatDate(filterMonthRange, "GMT", "MMMMM YYYY");
```

To:

```
var filterMonthRange = filterMonthRange.map(function(e) {return [Utilities.formatDate(e[0], "GMT", "MMMMM YYYY")]});
```

- In this case, `filterMonthRange` is 2 dimentional array like `[["January 2020"],,,]`. Please be careful this.

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, the format of cells "B2:B" are modified to `MMMMM YYYY`.

#### Sample script:

```
var filterMonthRange = sh.getRange('B2:B'+sh.getLastRow());
filterMonthRange.setNumberFormat("mmmm\" \"yyyy");
```

- When above script is run, the cell format is modified.

### References:

- [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))
- [setNumberFormat()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I used Pattern 1 and it worked exactly as expected. Thank you!

Comment: @adsigel Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.